# Using PowerShell to FTP to label printer - mimic command-line FTP command

Tags: powershell, printing, ftp, intermec

I'm trying to print files to an Intermec printer. I can do it with `ftp` command like:

```
put C:\myfile.prn pr1
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with PowerShell and I've been able to upload files but I'm not sure how execute the last part, which is the port of the printer `pr1`.

This is what I got so far.

```
$Dir = "C:\files"    
$ftp = "ftp://printerip/pr1/" 
$user = "admin" 
$pass = "pass"  

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)  

#list every sql server trace file 
foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.prn")) { 
    "Uploading $item..." 
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$item.Name) 
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 
}
```

Comment: *"execute the last part which is the port of the printer 'pr1'"* - what does that mean?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl basically trying to send the same command  as if I'm in cmd line. Put c:\file.prn pr1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading the local file `myfile.prn` to the remote "file" `pr1`.

So do the same in PowerShell:

```
$ftp = "ftp://printerip/pr1"
$webclient.UploadFile($ftp, $item.FullName)
```

Comment: doh.. I was so close. Thanks for your help!